# Counting One-To-One Functions

Tags: combinatorics

How many one-to-one functions are there from the set with $m$ elements to one with $n$ elements?

**Solution:**

Knowing that $m \le n$ for being one-to-one. Let the domain be $a_1, \cdots, a_m$ and they map to one element in the codomain. When we choose what $a_1$ maps to we cannot use it again. Then for choosing what $a_2$ maps to we have $(n-1)$ ways to choose.

My question is how do we get an expression by the product rule from counting? I am stuck at the part where I left off.

Comment: Just keep doing it. $n\times (n-1)\times \cdots (n-m+1).$

Comment: This might be a silly question, but why $m+1$?

Comment: Because it starts with $n-0$ so for having $m$ products you have to go from $0$ to $m-1$ but $n-(m-1)=n-m+1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $n$ choices for the image of $a_1$, then $n-1$ choices for the image of $a_2$, $\dots$, and finally $n-m+1$ choices for the image of $a_m$, yielding
$$\prod_{k=1}^m (n-k+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$$